# Looking for some image management that allows applying tags via voice recognition

Tags: file-management, image-viewer, voice-recognition, tags

I want an image to be displayed/selected, I want to speak keywords, and then have them applied to the image. That's pretty much it.

The more I can automate it via Speaking, the better. Being able to go forward/back among images and add a keyword/tag with voice would be awesome.

Needs to work on Win10.

I have so many images, for wallpapers mostly, and I'm trying to sort through them (Easily over 100k). Manually clicking and/or dragging, typing... it takes a lot more time than just being able to vocalize the key things in the image would and having something apply that information.